# getting values from checkboxes

Tags: java, swing

I have 5 checkboxes which are monday, tuesday, wednessday, thursday, friday.
I am trying to get Value from these checkboxes when any of them is selected.
But I realize that when all of them are not selected, the ones that are not selected have null values when I print it. How can I only print the values of only the one that are selected without the null values in between. That is when I do `System.out.print();` assuming I select tuesday and thursday alone I get response like `null tuesday null thursday null`

Below is what I did.

This is the code

```
private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    System.out.print(mon+ " " +tue+" "+wed +" "+thus+" " +fri); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mon+ " " +tue+" "+wed +" "+thus+" " +fri);

}                                     

private void mondayBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) { 
   if(mondayBox.isSelected())
   {
       mon = mondayBox.getText();

   } 
   else
   {
     mon = " ";
   }
}                                          

private void tuesdayBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt)
{
   if(tuesdayBox.isSelected())
   {
       tue = tuesdayBox.getText();
   }
   else
   {
       tue = "";
   }// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void wedBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
   if(wedBox.isSelected())
   {
       wed = wedBox.getText();
   }else
   {
       wed = "";
   }        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void thurBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
   if(thurBox.isSelected())
   {
       thus = thurBox.getText();
   }else
   {
       thus = "";
   }         // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void friBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) { 
if(friBox.isSelected())
   {
       fri = friBox.getText();
   }else
   {
       fri = "";
   }        
}
```

Comment: Why not combine all the ItemListeners to one single ItemListener?

Comment: Check whether value is null or not and then print them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning null because all those variables "mon", "tue", "wed", etc.. will be set to empty only if the CheckBox changes it state.

Try this:

```
btnSelected.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getSelected());
            }
        });

public String getSelected() {
    String days = "";
    for (Component c : getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JCheckBox)
            if (((JCheckBox) c).isSelected())
                days += ((JCheckBox) c).getText() + ",";
    }
    return days;
}
```

What We're doing here is verifying all components of the current panel, if the component is a checkbox and is selected, then We add it's text to the String "days".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Gabriel, i have done exactly as you have advised but there seem to be something wrong. when i try to print out the value nothing shows. i dont know if the variable "days" does not get the values.

Comment: @AgwuChile, maybe your checkboxes belong to another JPanel. See the panel where you add your checkboxes, something like `myPanel.add(checkbox)`. Now you can edit the code above, where you see `for (Component c : getComponents())` change for `for (Component c : myPanel.getComponents())` and see if it works.

Comment: No problem, @AgwuChile, you can check it as the right answer for future searchs. I'm glad I could help =D

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually easy. Declare `tue, wed, mon` etc in your class context initializing to empty String `""`. All the `null` will go away. For example:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
  String tue = "";
  String wed = "";
  .........
  JCheckBox tuesDayBox;

}
```